# Show possible entries while user entering the address UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, dictionary, street-address

My requirement is as follows,

User writes address in UITextfield, based on that address latitude and longitude will be fetched and it would be shown on map.

But client's one more requirement is, while typing the address on textfield, possible entries of address would be shown under textfield.

I can not understand how to get possible entries of address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Google Places autocomplete API. It provide you addreess that you want in list.

For More info please refer this example that help you to how to use Google Places autocomplete with your application

https://maniacdev.com/2013/10/ios-completion-providing-search-with-autocompletion-and-map-marking-using-google-places

you can find sample code for the same on Github find Below link for this

https://github.com/chenyuan/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete
[It's an objective-c wrapper for the Google Places Autocomplete API.]

Hope this may help.

Comment: please try this new repo: https://github.com/hkellaway/HNKGooglePlacesAutocomplete, which is being actively maintained.